# How to enter a tab char on command line?

Tags: macos, bash

In an interactive bash terminal how do I enter a tab character?  For example, if I wanted to use sed to replace "_" with tabs I'd like to use:

```
echo $string | sed 's/[_]/TAB/g'
```

Where TAB means the tab key.  This works in a shell script not interactively where when I hit the tab key I get no character and a clank noise sounds.  I've also tried `\t` but it only places t's in the string and not tabs.

Note this is mac osx.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Precede it with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> to suppress the usual expansion behavior.

Comment: I'm getting strange results.  Entering Control + V one time does nothing.  Doing it a 2nd times gives me a ^V where I wanted a tab and replaces the "_" chars with nothing.

Comment: @grok12: "Precede", not "replace".  `[Control]` + `[V]`, followed by `[Tab]`.

Comment: works on Linux too. I guess it's more to do with bash than the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is tagged "bash"... using the ["ANSI-C quoting" feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) of the Bash shell is probably preferable. It expands ANSI C-style escape sequences such as `\t` and `\n` and returns the result as a single-quoted string.

```
echo $string | sed $'s/_/\t/g'
```

This does not rely on your terminal understanding the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (insert next character literally) key binding—some may not. Also, because all the "invisible" characters can be represented literally, your solution can be copy-pasted without loss of information, and will be much more obvious/durable if you're using including this `sed` invocation in a script that other people might end up reading.

Also note that macOS's version of `sed` is the BSD version. GNU `sed` will interpret character escapes like `\t` in the replacement pattern just fine, and you wouldn't even need above workaround.

You can install GNU sed with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), and it should be made available as `gsed`, but  [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) might supersede your system's `sed` depending on how you have your `$PATH` variable arranged.