# replacing tabs with single tab in sed

Tags: regex, windows, sed

I want to replace all multiple tabs with a single tab with sed.
I am trying to use

```
sed 's:\t+:\t:' .\text.CSV > newtext.csv
```

but this doesn't seem to work

If I open in sublime and replace by regex all `\t+` to `\t` it works properly

what is wrong with my sed?

Also, if I replace tabs with a comma with

```
sed 's:\t\t*:,:g' text.CSV > newtext.csv
```

I get this kind of line

```
264262360,20030826,200308,2003,2003.6466,BUS,EMPLOYER,,,,,,BUS,,, ,,,,,,,,,,0,051,051,05,1,3.4,12,2,12,5.24866163479182,1
```

Comment: Remember `+` means one or more so can also be written `\t\t*`

Comment: If `\t` isn't working, try using [Ctrl]-[v] [Tab] ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392249/how-to-enter-a-tab-char-on-command-line)) if working in a a *nix terminal. Copy-pasting a tab character might work, but in my terminal tabs were replaced by four spaces.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use `tr` to replace multiple tabs with a single one:

```
tr -s '\t' '\t' < inputfile > outfile
```

The `-s` option squeezes repeats:

> **-s**, **--squeeze-repeats**
>
> ```
>       replace each input sequence of a repeated character that is
>       listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character
> ```

Comment: NOte that `tr -s '\t'` is enough to squeeze, the second `'\t'` is not necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Use `-r` option and `g` flag:

```
sed -r 's:\t+:\t:g' text.CSV > newtext.csv
```

`-r` to make `+` to work.

`g` flag to replace all occurrences.

**UPDATE**

If your `sed` does not support `-r` option, try following instead:

```
sed 's:\t\t*:\t:g' text.CSV > newtext.csv
```

Comment: @NickGinanto, What OS do you use?

Comment: I am trying on win7 with powershell. Also tried this with cygwin

Comment: @NickGinanto, Where did you download the `sed`?

Comment: I didn't, I happily found it :) where should I download it?

Comment: @NickGinanto, In my Windows 7 box, there's no `sed` found.

Comment: maybe it takes it from the git installation maybe?

Comment: @NickGinanto, I installed `git`, .. using `sed` included their, I get the expected result. See [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5W3lxMO.png).

Comment: @NickGinanto, What is the output of `sed --version`? In my box, it gives `GNU sed version 4.2.1 ....`.

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

`sed "s/\t\+/\t\g" test.csv >> newtest.csv`