# generate a file through SQL Server by query

Tags: sql-server, export

I'm working on a project which is based on daily activity.So i need to provide multiple reports at the end of the day by using export/Import Wizard it will take around 30-40 min of time.
In this case am thinking that i can write a query to generate these reports are done by a single query.It saves my time.
There is any chance to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You can create a schedule job in SQL server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: A "report" is generally more than just rows of raw data. Define your goal more precisely before you start choosing any particular path.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options.  Two good options to save your time, and generate the results of many queries in file format, are:

### SSRS

[SSRS Scheduled Reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872783.aspx), if you have that available to you.

> To configure a subscription to deliver a report to a file share
>
> ```
> In the Configuration Manager console, navigate to System CenterConfiguration Manager / Site Database / Computer Management /
> ```
>
> Reporting / Reporting Services / , and expand the
>   node.
>
> ```
> In the results pane, right-click a report and then click New Subscription.
>
> On the Subscription Delivery page of the Create Subscription Wizard, specify the delivery properties for this report subscription.
> ```
>
> From the Report delivered by drop-down list, select Windows File
>   Share. For more details about the options on this page, see Report
>   Subscription Dialog Box: Subscription Delivery Tab.
>
> ```
> Click Next to continue.
>
> On the Subscription Schedule page of the Create Subscription Wizard, configure the schedule by which the report will be generated
> ```
>
> and delivered to the file share. For more details about the options on
>   this page, see Report Subscription Dialog Box: Subscription Schedule
>   Tab.
>
> ```
> Click Next to continue.
>
> On the Subscription Parameters page of the Create Subscription Wizard, specify any parameters that this report needs to run. For more
> ```
>
> details about the options on this page, see Report Subscription Dialog
>   Box: Subscription Parameters Tab.
>
> ```
> Click Next to continue.
>
> On the Summary page of the Create Subscription Wizard, review the subscription that will be created and then click Next.
>
> On the Confirmation page of the Create Subscription Wizard, review the actions taken and then click Close to exit the wizard.
> ```

---

### SQLCMD

And using the Windows scheduler or a batch file run by hand to have [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) run one or more queries and/or stored procedures on a schedule, outputting to one or more files.

Both Excel and Libreoffice will read tab delimited files; to do so with sqlcmd see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829596/how-to-use-tab-as-column-separator-in-sqlcmd).