# How to use multiple characters as a separator in SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm running a SQL query in PowerShell using the SQLCMD, [one of the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829596/how-to-use-tab-as-column-separator-in-sqlcmd) shows how to use TAB as a separator. I'd like to have a fancier sequence of characters such as TAB-Comma-Space or Tab-Comma-Tab. 
I've tried

```
-s `"`t,`t`"
-s `"`t`, `"
```

but it still uses a single Tab as the separator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017).

**-s** col_separator
Specifies the column-separator character. The default is a blank space. This option sets the sqlcmd scripting variable SQLCMDCOLSEP. To use characters that have special meaning to the operating system such as the ampersand (&), or semicolon (;), enclose the character in quotation marks ("). **The column separator can be any 8-bit character.**

You might want to think about using a character like the hat/caret (^) as your delimiter and mass replacing that in the output. Not sure what single character would be least likely to conflict with your dataset.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what I figured out myself but forgot to post my answer here.