# Powershell SQL query not properly exporting to CSV?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powershell, csv

> I need to retrieve rows of data from a few columns within a table.
>
> I need to automate this.
>
> I've decided to use a batch file.
>
> The command I've been running is.

`osql -S .\sqlexpress -E -i "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\eventdatetime24hr.sql" -o "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\queryOut.csv"`

It produces an output that looks like this:

Pic:

https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/business6/uploads/sqlteam/original/2X/9/98ed243059c8a3e9ad61a25a441086785932c3c9.png

As you can see, the output looks gross.

I need to feed it into another application, however, I can only do this is there is a separate cell for each column and row of data.

I don't know how to do this, can anyone please assist?

The columns are: eventdatetime, eventid, sNarrative

Comment: you can try `SQLPS` PowerShell module to query, it gives object as output and same can be exported to CSV using `Export-CSV` cmdlet

Comment: I tried this but I didn't understand it

Comment: where did you get stuck in using `SQLPS` ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, `osql` is deprecated and subject to removal in future releases of SQL Server. Consider using `sqlcmd` for command line usage, or native Powershell commands such as `Invoke-SqlCmd` or even [dbatools](https://dbatools.io).

The result you've got is likely caused by inappropriate column separator. In a CSV file, comma `,` is often used as colunn separator. The catch is *often*. In several non-USian locales, the separator character is something else. Tab and semicolon `;` are popular alternatives.

The spreadsheet application uses different a separator than what the file contains. Thus it doesn't understand that content is to be splitted into separate colunns. To fix this, either create the file with default separator or tell the spreadsheet to use alternative a separator.

To change the separator character, use syntax described in [another an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6127274/503046):

```
:: cmd
sqlcmd -S ServerName -E -Q"select * from mytable" -s"   " -o results.txt
# Powershell
sqlcmd -S ServerName -E -Q"select * from mytable" -s `"`t`" -o results.txt
```

The spreadsheet is likely to have a functionality such as Excel's "Text to columns" or "Import text wizard". Use either to import the document and pick the right separator. To see which it really is, open the file in Notepad first.